# Converting SQL numbers from negative to positive

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    hl.hotel_nbr "VENDOR NUMBER", 
    hl.hotel_name "VENDOR NAME",
    p.accounting_date "COLLECTED DATE",
    CASE 
        WHEN td.chg_charge = '210' 
            THEN nvl(p.amount, 0)
            ELSE 0 
    END MARGIN_COLLECTED
```

This is my SQL script and margin_collected always comes out as a negative number. I am trying to alter this script so margin_collected will be positive.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

use `abs` function to make it a positive value

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE 
    WHEN td.chg_charge = '210' 
        THEN ABS(nvl(p.amount, 0))
        ELSE 0 
END MARGIN_COLLECTED
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this site about [ABS](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/abs.php)